# Is there any Spring-Security-based production-ready security package for Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm designing the security subsystem for a new product. The system requires the following:

- Complex user/group/permission model, both service-level and domain-level (ACL)
- Administration UI for the above
- Rules performed upon user actions (account disable on failed login, password complexity requirements, etc).

Before going ahead and implementing most of the features that Spring Security (2.x) lacks, I was wondering if anyone is familiar with and can recommend a package that may already implement / support these requirements? ideally JAR + WAR that can be dropped into the project and support everything off-the-shelf.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but you might be interested in checking out [jSecurity](http://www.jsecurity.org/).  It is a well thought out security framework that handles authentication, authorization, and fine-grained permissions.  But from what I can gather, much like [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/), they try not to make assumptions about how this data is stored and organized.  (I haven't found, for example, a reference implementation for User, Roles, Permissions, etc. in a database.)

Note that the JSecurity project has permanently moved to the Apache Software Foundation and is now known as the [Apache Shiro](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SHIRO) project.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting you asked, I also have a very similar requirement and have been searching this for a while. I gave up and started doing it myself and have some decent progress in the last 2 weeks. Currently I have support for domain ids that are not necessarily Long, it could be anything such as a wild-card string to denote a group of things that could be granted to an authority (ROLE, GROUP, USER) or a String id or even a long. Multiple permission types each with their or sets of permissions can be defined and these permission types could be assigned as supported to a secured entity and the instances be protected by them, so you don't have the limitation of a maximum of 32 possible permissions across the system. Also you could use any actual or virtual entities in the ACL configuration. All this is based on the new (3.0.0.R1) of Spring security with method expression support and it works fairly well. The whole thing uses hibernate so you can take advantage of the transparent persistence and distributed caching. There are lots of rough edges, but being a proof of concept its expected. Anyways let me know if you are interested and we could collaborate to make this useful to us and probably others too.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Are you willing to open-source it? if so, I'd love to have a look at what you've already done

Shai